# Comiplation time: MingGW vs. MSVC

Tags: c, mingw, visual-studio-2010

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior with the MSVC compiler, compared to the MinGW.
I'm trying to build a library for windows (.dll) to include in a bigger MSVC project.

My library has 108 .c files with their .h files. The average size of the .c files is 3.3 KB (size varies from 1 KB to 9.7 KB). Each .c file is only one equation that outputs one double based on double inputs. For example:

```
double value_p3_D2(double a, double b, double c, ... (about 30 inputs)){
    double outval = -(-(sin(a) * sin(b) - cos(a) * cos(b)) * sin(d * (m2 *
    (-sin(f) * g + cos(g) * g) * (cos(c) ..... up to 9.7 kB of equation text;
    return outval;
}
```

It compiled with MinGW 4.8 32 bit in less than 20 minutes, the resulting DLL is 611 KB in size (each object file .o, for each .c file, varies from 1 KB to 8 KB).

However, if I compile it with MSVC 2010 32 bits it takes forever. I waited 24 hours and it has not even processed 20% of the files (I check the progress by the output .obj files, wich also vary from 1 KB to 8 KB). I'm not exaggerating.

I've tried some MSVC compiler switches such as /Od which disables optimization, but I do not see any improvement in compile time, however, object files are 1 to 2.5MB is size!!
I'm using Qt to compile even if my project is purely C without using any Qt libraries.
I used the switches this way:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2 #forget about optimizing speed
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Od #disable optimization
```

I've also tried MSVC 2012 64 bits and MSVC 2013 64 bits but I get similar results.

Are there any MSVC compiler switches that I could use to improve speed while keeping the size small?
I would love to have the same compile time & result as the MinGW compiler.

Any help would be appreciated!

PS: I've also taken a look on how to convert a MinGW dll into a library that can be imported in a MSVC project here:
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs
However it does not look straightforward... Any other examples on how to do so are welcome :)

Comment: With qmake, your options are limited. cl (the microsoft compiler) isn't the fastest one out there, and qmake is also not the fastest of things. cl by default uses only one thread, i'm not sure about qmake. but you can try adding the /MP[n] flag (where [n] is replaced with the number of CPUs). Personally, I'd think it'd be worth to try out CMake with Ninja (or just ninja, if you're into that sort of thing) if your default build is 20 minutes long.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. CMake is not a compiler itself right? I mean, it will set up a project in visual studio that you can build using the microsoft compiler right? I just tried to use CMake and build it from the microsoft visual studio 2012 but it still takes too long. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:
'code'
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(mylib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( "mylib/" ) 
ADD_LIBRARY(
mylib
SHARED
code/libentry.c
code/libentry.h
code/calc1.c
code/calc1.h
...
)
'code'